# Google Cloud - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, jpa, jsf, google-cloud-platform, tomcat8

Guys I have a Java web application which was developed in JSF + JPA + Hibernate which is running on a Linux server on Google Cloud.

**VM instance details**

Machine type - n1-standard-1 (1 vCPUj, 3.75 GB of memory)

**Software Operational**

System Debian (9.11)

**Software**

Apache (2.4.25)

Google-Fluentd (1.6.17)

OpenJDK (1.8.0)

Stackdriver-Agent (5.5.2)

Tomcat (8.5.14.0)

The problem I'm having and the following, I have a URL: **https://app.example.com/login.xhtml** which the user normally accesses the application, but the moment he clicks logoff the application it should be directed to the login screen, because that's exactly what happens on my localhost machine, but on the Google Cloud server it is directed to this url: **http://127.0.0.1:8080/login.xhtml**

And give the following error as the image below:

[image]

Does anyone know help me in this?

NOTE: I use the CloudFlare service to add SSL to my subdomain https://app.example.com/login.xhtml

Comment: So if you remove jsf, jpa and put a plain html file in ther with just 'hello world' content, you **don't** get a 404 due to a redirect?

Comment: @Kukeltje I can access normally, and only when I exit the application, when I click the exit button, it directs me to the wrong url http://127.0.0.1:8080/login.xhtml

Comment: Ok, noticed your edit in your question. Most likely this is something in your code (or a misconfiguration in the google-cloud-platform, but not something java, jpa, jsf or tomcat-8 related

Comment: Ok, so someone could tell me where this configuration will be done on my server to solve this problem?

Comment: check the 'most likely' first... your code

Comment: Hello
I believe it is not my code because previously I used Digital Ocean as a cloud server and that same application did not have this problem.

So I think it may be some configuration of Google Cloud Firewall or Tomcat itself.

Comment: Or it silently 'fixed' this for you ;-)

Comment: Hello, no, the problem continues. I'm new to Google Cloud and I don't know how to configure all the settings, all I have done so far was searching the internet and their material.

Comment: No one who can help me? I really need to solve this problem for my application to work perfectly on Google Cloud.

Comment: Like I said, your question is too broad, you did not try to narrow things down (and provide a [mcve]. Add logging/debug etc... Investigate...

Comment: I understand, but as I said the problem is not in my code, because this same application works as desired on another linux server from Digital Ocean. But what kind of code do you need to support me to solve this headache?